# Getting rid of linker warning in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build, linker-errors

How do I get rid of this linker warning that appears every time I build my project in XCode?

```
Ld build/Sidestep.build/Release/Sidestep.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Sidestep normal x86_64
cd /Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep/build/Release -F/Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep/build/Release -F/Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep/frameworks -F/Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep -filelist /Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep/build/Sidestep.build/Release/Sidestep.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Sidestep.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework Security -framework Cocoa -framework SystemConfiguration -framework IOKit -framework Sparkle -o /Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep/build/Sidestep.build/Release/Sidestep.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Sidestep

ld: warning: directory '/Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep/frameworks' following -F not found
```

I don't have the folder `/Users/Chetan/Development/Sidestep/frameworks` anymore, since I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that directory from the "framework search paths" in the build settings for the project, or for that target.